# C# storage divide

Tags: c#, storage, hardware

I'm currently learning C# and have a problem.
I wrote a program that shows what hardware you got and it won't divide the storage.

Here is the code:

```
int inGB = int32.parse(getComponent("win32_DiskDrive", "size")) / 1024 / 1024;
```

It can't divide because of a character which is not a number.
anyone got an idea?

Comment: break up the line into multiple statements and see exactly which one fails - it's certainly not the division that's the problem.

Comment: when posting a question on stackoverflow try to attach the _exact_ error and exception message. also get a habit of reading them yourself when your program stops working - they're there to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting `OverflowException` becuase size is represented by `ulong` not an `int`.

Also, the value of `size` is bytes, so you are showing size in MB not GB.

I don't know how you've implemented the `getComponent` method, but it can look like this:

```
ManagementClass driveClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
ManagementObjectCollection drives = driveClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject drive in drives)
{
    PropertyData property = drive.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>()
                                 .Single(p => p.Name == "Size");
    ulong sizeInMb = (ulong) property.Value/1024/1024;

    // rest of your code
}
```

You can have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) for the documentation of `Win32_DiskDrive`

Comment: **Stack** overflow exception?